# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/ui/views/properties/IPropertySource

Tags: eclipse-rcp, eclipse-gef

I have a GEF plugin that needs to show the Properties tab.
I have added the IPropertySource interface and implemented its methods.In the model class,which is implementing IAdaptable, the following has been included:

```
@Override
    public Object getAdapter(Class adapter) {
        if (adapter == IPropertySource.class) {
            propertySource = new ParentPropertySource(parent);
            return propertySource;
        }
        return null;

    }
```

I have also added the "org.eclipse.ui.views" in Dependencies in plugin.xml
But unable to debug as to why this runtime exception is occuring.

Kindly guide.

Comment: Check that all the required plugins are include in the Run Configuration

Comment: All the required plugins are included .Still the problem persists.

Comment: did you also add the dependency to the `MANIFEST.MF` file? Also, try closing and opening eclipse, and completely rebuilding the project. Sometimes this helps